# Devolver valor de una funcion al main

Tags: c++, funciones, variables

Quiero sacar el el valor de una variable de una función hacia el main, pero no lo devuelve. La función es un acumulador de contagiados cada cierto día y quiero sacar el promedio. El programa no corre porque al sacar el promedio la variable "c" toma el valor del main que es 0, cuando debería tener el valor que extraigo de la función. Por ejemplo: Si introduzco para 4 días, el total de contagios es 3 y el promedio debería ser 1,5.
La serie de contagios es 1,2,4,8... cada 3 dias.

```
  #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int total_contagiados(int D,int c)
{int Total=0,i,doble=1; c=0;
    for(i=1; i<=D; i=i+3)
    {Total=Total+doble; 
     doble=2*doble;
     c++;
    }
    return Total;
}

int main()
{int D,c=0,total; float prom;
    cout<<"A cuantos dias quiere calcular los contagiados?"; cin>>D;
    total=total_contagiados(D,c); cout<<c;
    prom=total/c;
    cout<<"Total contagiados al dia:"<<D<<" son:"<<total<<endl;
    cout<<"Promedio de contagiados al dia:"<<D<<" es:"<<prom;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lo que tu devuelves es solo la variable correspondiente al total, en ningún momento devuelves otra cosa más. Por otra parte lo que tu pasas por parámetro es el valor de la variable, en este caso se crea una copia de la variable que será utilizada en la función. Si quieres modificar una variable que pasas por parámetro dentro de una función, entonces debes pasarla por referencia usando el operador `&`.

Comment: tu variable `c` será modificada, por lo tanto, en tu función tendrías que enviarlo como parámetro a `c` con el operador `&` => `total_contagiados(int D,int &c)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el mundo hay personas diferentes con el mismo nombre.

Con las funciones sucede algo parecido. Puedes tener variables diferentes con el mismo nombre.

En el ámbito de la función `total_contagiados`, `int D` y `int c` son parámetros que solo existen dentro de la función.

De forma similar en la función `main`, `D` y `c` son variables que solo existen dentro de ella. Estos 2 pares de variables son independientes. Cada cuál tiene su propio espacio en la memoria y no hay ningún tipo de conexión entre ambos.

---

Una opción es declarar las variables fuera de las funciones. Así ambas son capaces de verlas y existen durante toda la ejecución del programa en un ámbito mayor:

```
int D;
int c;

int total_contagiados()
{
    ...
    // Puedes acceder a D y c aquí
}

int main()
{
    int total;
    float prom;
    ...
    // Y aquí también
}
```

---

A veces no quieres que las variables sean visibles para todas las funciones o que vivan durante todo el programa.

Una técnica para "prestar" una variables es pasar las variables por referencia.

Eso lo puedes hacer agregando `&` antes del nombre de la variable. Así:

```
int total_contagiados(int &D, int &c)
{
    ...
}
```

Las referencias en realidad son una versión más amigable de los punteros. Conservan la dirección de memoria de la variable que les pasas como parámetro. Entonces las modificaciones se hacen sobre esa dirección de memoria. Resultando en modificaciones sobre la variable original.

Si esta explicación te pareció abrumadura, piensa en las referencias como si se trataran de alias para las variables originales. Cuando entiendas los punteros cobrará sentido.

Por cierto, esto mismo también se podría haber hecho con punteros, pero hay que aprovechar lo que C++ nos ofrece y en este caso es más simple hacerlo así.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, por la explicación y la ayuda.